# How to setup multistage builds for a ReactJS App with server side rendering

Tags: reactjs, dockerfile

How do I configure this as a multi stage build

yarn start maps to

```
"start": "nodemon ./server-build/index.js",
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14.17.3-alpine AS build

RUN apk add --no-cache build-base gcc autoconf automake libtool zlib-dev libpng-dev nasm

RUN npm i nodemon -g

WORKDIR /app/web-web

ENV PATH /app/web-web/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY package.json /app/web-web/package.json

RUN yarn install --network-timeout 1000000000

COPY . /app/web-web

RUN yarn run build:staging

COPY . /app/web-web

EXPOSE 3006

CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Warning NOT Tested code.

The Dockerfile below is not tested and you must consider it as a starting point.

Missing some info, the `apk` packages are required only for build or else to run ?

I suggest you read about [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/)

```
###############################################################
# This stage do:
# 1. Install required software
# 2. Copy package.json and install deps
###############################################################
FROM node:14.17.3-alpine AS build

# This packet are required ONLY for build ??? Otherwise add on final stage
RUN apk add --no-cache build-base gcc autoconf automake libtool zlib-dev libpng-dev nasm

WORKDIR /app/web-web

ENV PATH /app/web-web/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY package.json /app/web-web/package.json

RUN yarn install --network-timeout 1000000000

###############################################################
# This stage do:
# 1. copy node_modules from build stage to this image
# 2. build app and run
###############################################################
FROM node:14.17.3-alpine AS final

WORKDIR /app/web-web
# Magic append here: I copy from prev stage (build) to this one
COPY --from=build /app/web-web .
COPY . /app/web-web

RUN npm i nodemon -g

RUN yarn run build:staging

EXPOSE 3006

CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

Comment: The file which I used is currently being in use, not sure what do you mean that its not tested

Comment: The code I have written in the answer is not tested.